# VirtualBox running Ubuntu 11.10 in Win7 is suddenly way too slow

Tags: virtualbox, ubuntu-11.10

For two months I've been running Ubuntu 11.10 64bits in VirtualBox 4.1.12r77245 but today everything has been really slow, freezing all the time. I've had to restart the VM about 7 times already because Ubuntu just freezed in the middle of a task. I'm using my laptop, it's a LG P420 i5 with 4gb ram. I don't know if it could be an update of Ubuntu or VB, but I really need it to work. Any guesses?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would first check your setup and make sure that you're allowing the VM to have enough RAM and CPU Speed. What you had when you set it up and used it for the first two months, may not be enough to support it now.

If that doesn't work, just try to uninstall you Oracle VB, while saving your VDI and such files, so that your OS and files are kept safe. Then, install the latest version of the VB from the VB website.

If *that* doesn't solve your problem, run Ubuntu updates through terminal.

Other than that, I don't know what to tell you.